# Approximate X given 5 function values and y values

Tags: approximation, excel

Given
5 Lines(table)
X values and corresponding Y1,Y2,...Y5.
How can I calculate the approximate X value given the corresponding Y's?

How can I tweak the formula if I want to weight to bias the calculation towards corresponding line, say Y1?

Right now, I am just looking at the Line chart to estimate the X.
I am using Excel, so preferable to have solution that will work on Excel formula or VBA or I can just translate it.

[image: Date Table, Line chart, and sample Y's for X to be calculated.]

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jonathan.  Could you please explain the sense in which just one $X$ value is supposed to correspond to multiple $Y$ values?  What is the underlying *statistical* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for asking @whuber.
I have an object with 5 sensor and the reading of signal quality is on Y axis. 
X axis is  the distance of the object from the wall.
As I move away the object, we can observe the signal quality changes.
Given the signal quality value (Ys), what is the approximate object distance distance from the wall?
Is my explanation make sense?

Comment: It *sounds* like you just want to predict $x$ from the $y_i:$ that is, this is a pretty standard multiple regression problem.  It is strange, though, that $x$ varies so relatively little: it is practically constant.  This may make it difficult to estimate $x$ with much precision.  The issue of weighting is still obscure: yes, regression methods can incorporate such weights, *but it depends on what the weight means.*  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: Right. I want to predict x from the yi. Since I am doing it manually, I mainly use Y1 to predict the x, in the sample Y1= 82.40 so it is easy to predict X. But if the Y1=86, we can have 2 values of x, that is where the Y2-Y5 comes in.

Comment: I need to satisfy X that will fit to Y1 and Y2(or Y3-Y5). Therefore weight define which Y is the main predictor for X (Y1 in this case, 60%) and supporting predictor (Y2-Y5, 10% each). I just made up the 60% and 10% since I am doing it manually.

Comment: I will adjust it when we got the solution/formula.
BTW the picture I provided is just 1 set of data. I have 100s of this to predict their x.